# system() keeps returning 127

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am developing a shared-library `L` which is used by an other system service `S`. In my program I need to call a small program `P`, which uses Oracle shared libraries.

The small program `P` is packaged and installed correctly, and the environment variables, such as `PATH`,`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` are set correctly. I can run `P` on command line without any problem.

But when service `S` call my library `L` which runs the small program `P` via `system()`, it gives me a return code `127`. I've googled, people says it's a `command not found` error, probably a `PATH` issue, so I've tried with absolute path like the following

```
int status = system("/usr/bin/myprog --args");
if (status < 0) { ... }
ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
```

`ret` still equals `127`.

Any idea please ? Thank you.

**Update**
It turns out that the service `S` is launched via command `daemon`, in its `init.d` script, I have found the following line:

```
daemon /usr/bin/myserv
```

if I `export` explicitly all my environment variables (`PATH`, `ORACLE_HOME` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`), it works. I don't know if `daemon` eliminates my environment variables.

Comment: You should check whether `status` is `-1` before calling `WEXITSTATUS`. If it is `-1` then it means `system` failed and `WEXITSTATUS` is not valid. If it is not `-1` then the `WEXITSTATUS` value is returned by your program and so we can't tell you what it means since we don't have the source code to your program.

Comment: it's already done, still the same.

Comment: What is already done? What is the same? Could you not be clearer? If you mean `status` has been checked and is not `-1` then please read the second part of the comment - the `WEXITSTATUS` is returned by `myprog`. There is no way we can tell you what a return value of `127` means since we don't have the source code to `myprog`.

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean I have checked the returned value of `system`, if it's `-1`, I just log a error message, `if (status != -1)`, I pass `status` to `WEXITSTATUS`, then the macro returns `127`.

Answer (score 1):

this excerpt from the man page for `system()`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.,  fork(2)  failed),  and  the
   return  status  of the command otherwise.  
This latter return status is
   in the format specified in wait(2).  
Thus, the exit code of the command
   will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   
In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127)."
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

indicates the 127 means that `/bin/sh` could not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the answer:[How to make unix service see environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables),the environment variables are removed in init.d script.